# VideoJs Live Streaming

Tags: html, video.js, http-live-streaming, video-player

I'm facing a problem while streaming with videojs. It's like if the player is playing segments in sequence order. I want to force it to play the last downloaded segment. is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Hi Ayoub, any updates on this?

Comment: I spend months working on this problem. I reached out to the videoJs team they told me the player is configured by default to read n-3 segment (the server generated the nth segment). They told that they are working on a new version that will come soon.

Comment: I tried to force the player to always read the last segment. But the that generated so many issues. this results in some synchronisation problems and player tries to fetched segments and sometimes it fails and it keeps seeking for another segment.

Comment: Hove some updates about this ?